# How to set the size of the buffer in xtermjs?

Tags: xtermjs

I know I can clear the buffer. by `.clear()` method.
But can I restrain the size of the buffer in terms of memory or number of lines?
Can somebody help me on this or point to the docs? Because in docs I am not able to find a clear solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit Late, hope this could still help.

The `Terminal` object contains a reference to `buffer`, you can access a property `x` & `y`, which you can limit against.

`x` = number of characters on a line
`y` = number of lines

You could try something like this

```
const maxBufferLines = 10;
terminal.on('key', (key, ev) => {

  if (ev.keyCode === 13) {

    if (terminal._core.buffer.y >= maxBufferLines) {
      terminal.writeln('Max Buffer Size');
    } else {
      terminal.write('\r\n$ ');

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Malcor